# How to correctly show Notifications on Android and then Run or Just send message

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android application with the following logic of activities execution:

`if FIRST_RUN`: SplashScreeen -> Logon -> MainScreenTabHost

`if PUSH`:

1. `Not Running`: SplashScreeen -> Logon -> MainScreenTabHost
2. `Running`: `MainActivity` receives  a message

I can't figure out how to achieve this. My source code for `NotificationBar` item:

```
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Text in status bar", 
System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreenTabHost.class);//HERE PROBLEM
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification's title", "Notification's text", pIntent);
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
this.notificationManager.notify(1, notif);
```

This code always runs application `MainScreenTabHost`, but if application is not running it makes some init in Logon screen.

My question is: How can I check that application is running and if it's not then create an `Intent` to run Splash screen and cycle for FIRST RUN? On the other hand, if application is running I just want to send an `Intent` (maybe a Broadcast) for some operations.

And one thing, my service is not always running because it is run by a broadcast intent from Push Notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, i found next solution:

```
// Check current activity
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(this.getPackageName())) {
            Intent broadCast = new Intent(MainScreenTabHost.BROADCAST_ACTION);
            broadCast.putExtras(arg1.getExtras());
            sendBroadcast(broadCast);
        } else {

            this.sendNotif(arg1);
        }
```

So trick is: when fired onMessage method i check what activity currently on Top and if it's part of mine - i just send broadcast to it. If NOT a show notification with SplashScreen intent.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to be able to run spashScreen or not, depending on the state of the application.
You could try to register a BroadcastReceiver on your main activity, register an IntentFilter for a custom filter (let's say: NOTIFICATION_INTENT)

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NotificationActivity.NOTIFICATION_INTENT);         // notification click     intent
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Then, when creating notification you will have to create an intent to an notification activity that will broadcast the NOTIFICATION_INTENT.

The NotificationActivity should look like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NotificationActivity extends Activity{

    public static final String NOTIFICATION_INTENT = "notification_clicked_intent"; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.notification);

         // broadcast intent
         Intent i = new Intent();
         i.setAction(NOTIFICATION_INTENT);
         getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(i);

         /* Set activity result and send intent data */
         setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());

         /* Finish activity and return to parent activity */
         finish();
    }

}
```

The code for creating the notification will have something similar to this:

```
        // set intent to be opened on NotificationClick
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("key", icon);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY_RESULT, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Hope this helps.